# Read kml file with multiple placemarks in pykml

Tags: python, kml, pykml

In [pykml](http://pythonhosted.org/pykml/), I can read the first placemark in a file using the following code:

```
 with open(filename) as f:
     pm = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder
     print "got :"
     print pm.Placemark.LineString.coordinates
```

How can I read multiple placemarks in the same file into python?

Comment: The first line is not required, the with statement already creates an open file.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, @mwil.me!

Answer (score 9):

This works:

```
with open(filename) as f:
    doc = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder
for pm in doc.iterchildren():
    if hasattr(pm, 'LineString'):
        print pm.LineString.coordinates
```

Answer (score 9):

Edit: An even easier solution, assuming all placemarks are in one folder:

```
from pykml import parser

with open(filename) as f:
  folder = parser.parse(f).getroot().Document.Folder

for pm in folder.Placemark:
  print(pm.name)
```

---

You can also use features of the underlying xml library lxml to search for placemark elements.

```
from pykml import parser
from pykml.factory import nsmap

namespace = {"ns": nsmap[None]}

with open(filename) as f:
  root = parser.parse(f).getroot()
  pms = root.findall(".//ns:Placemark", namespaces=namespace)

  for pm in pms:
    print(pm.name)
```

If you specifically search for placemarks that have a Linestring child, you can also use xpath for more sophisticated searches.

```
pms = root.xpath(".//ns:Placemark[.//ns:LineString]", namespaces=namespace)
```