# Python Extract data from KML file containing multiple placemarks

Tags: python, kml

I have a KML file as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?><kml xmlns="http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1">
<Document>
<name>MST =T</name>
<description><![CDATA[<p>KML test file</p>
<p>This is a test version.</p>]]></description>
<Style id="spstyle5">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ff3EE23E</color>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff3EE23E</color>
        <width>4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
    <name>Track5</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
            <name>sp5_sp6_ Track</name>
            <description><![CDATA[<i>sp5_sp6_</i> track<br>pantrack id:5]]></description>
            <Placemark>
                <name>sp5_sp6_ MST</name>
                <description><![CDATA[<i> species sp5_sp6_</i> mst<br>long= 648.000 corte 0.250000]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#spstyle5</styleUrl>
                <MultiGeometry>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            8.000,8.000 6.000,7.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            5.000,7.000 6.000,7.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            3.000,8.000 5.000,7.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            2.000,8.000 3.000,8.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
                </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
</Folder>
<Style id="spstyle7">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ffBC77DC</color>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ffBC77DC</color>
        <width>4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
    <name>Track7</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
            <name>sp1_sp2_sp6_ Track</name>
            <description><![CDATA[<i>sp1_sp2_sp6_</i> track<br>pantrack id:7]]></description>
            <Placemark>
                <name>sp1_sp2_sp6_ MST</name>
                <description><![CDATA[<i> species sp1_sp2_sp6_</i> mst<br>long= 441.000 corte 0.250000]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#spstyle7</styleUrl>
                <MultiGeometry>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            11.000,6.000 12.000,6.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            12.000,6.000 12.000,4.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            12.000,4.000 11.000,3.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
                </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
</Folder>
<Style id="spstyle8">
    <IconStyle>
        <color>ff97287A</color>
        <Icon><href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/paddle/wht-blank.png</href></Icon>
    </IconStyle>
    <LineStyle>
        <color>ff97287A</color>
        <width>4</width>
    </LineStyle>
</Style>
<Folder>
    <name>Track8</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
            <name>sp3_sp6_sp4_sp6_ Track</name>
            <description><![CDATA[<i>sp3_sp6_sp4_sp6_</i> track<br>pantrack id:8]]></description>
            <Placemark>
                <name>sp3_sp6_sp4_sp6_ MST</name>
                <description><![CDATA[<i> species sp3_sp6_sp4_sp6_</i> mst<br>long= 757.000 corte 0.250000]]></description>
                <styleUrl>#spstyle8</styleUrl>
                <MultiGeometry>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            8.000,8.000 8.000,7.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            8.000,7.000 11.000,6.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            11.000,6.000 11.000,5.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            11.000,6.000 12.000,6.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
            <LineString>
                        <tessellate>true</tessellate>
                        <altitudeMode>clampToGround</altitudeMode>
                        <coordinates>
                            11.000,5.000 12.000,4.000
                        </coordinates>
                    </LineString>
                </MultiGeometry>
            </Placemark>
</Folder>

</Document>
</kml>
```

I want to extract separately the name of each placemark and all coordinates in the LineString tags associated with that placemark, resulting in something like:

```
Placemark A 
x, y
x, y
x, y
...
Placemark B
x, y
x, y
x, y
```

I have tried all the solutions proposed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33321223/read-kml-file-with-multiple-placemarks-in-pykml), but none of them works for my data. In fact, all solutions there are highly generic and no test data was provided for checking them against.

**Update**: I did some progress with the code below, which allow to extract all placemarks and linecoordinates (I was just forgetting the damned namespace):

```
from pykml import parser

filename = "output0.kml"
with open(filename) as f:
    root = parser.parse(f).getroot()
    pms = root.findall('.//{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}Placemark')
    lst = doc.findall('.//{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}LineString')

for pm in pms:
    print(pm.name)
for ls in lst:
    print(ls.coordinates)
```

But still can't figure out how to extract the coordinates *grouped by placemark*!

Comment: Is your question then resolved? Do note: you can answer your own question.

Comment: No, it isn't. I edited it just to point out my recebt efforts toward a solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Simply nest the `for` loops where inner parsing works off the outer parsing element. Also, you can use the built-in `etree` module since kml are xml files.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et

doc = et.parse("source.kml")

nmsp = '{http://earth.google.com/kml/2.1}'

for pm in doc.iterfind('.//{0}Placemark'.format(nmsp)):
    print(pm.find('{0}name'.format(nmsp)).text)

    for ls in pm.iterfind('{0}MultiGeometry/{0}LineString/{0}coordinates'.format(nmsp)):
        print(ls.text.strip().replace('\n',''))

# sp5_sp6_ MST
# 8.000,8.000 6.000,7.000
# 5.000,7.000 6.000,7.000
# 3.000,8.000 5.000,7.000
# 2.000,8.000 3.000,8.000
# sp1_sp2_sp6_ MST
# 11.000,6.000 12.000,6.000
# 12.000,6.000 12.000,4.000
# 12.000,4.000 11.000,3.000
# sp3_sp6_sp4_sp6_ MST
# 8.000,8.000 8.000,7.000
# 8.000,7.000 11.000,6.000
# 11.000,6.000 11.000,5.000
# 11.000,6.000 12.000,6.000
# 11.000,5.000 12.000,4.000
```